# How to disable DynamicProxies in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am developing existing project, where database access is coded like:

```
public UserDTO Login(string login, string password)
{
    return OnConnect<UserDTO>(db =>
    {
        var user = db.Users
            .Where(x => x.Name.Trim().ToLower() == login.ToLower().Trim())
            .FirstOrDefault();

        // validation..

        return user.ToUserDTO();
    });
}
```

The thing is after exiting this method my `user` property like: `user.PermissionGroup` is unaccessable, because it was living in `DynamicProxies`, but context is now closed.

After reading some stack'o posts, I managed to include properties, that I want to use after leaving `Login` method:

```
public UserDTO Login(string login, string password)
{
    return OnConnect<UserDTO>(db =>
    {
        var user = db.Users
            .Where(x => x.Name.Trim().ToLower() == login.ToLower().Trim())
            .Include("PermissionGroup")
            .Include("PermissionGroup.GroupActionPermissions")
            .Include("PermissionGroup.GroupActionPermissions.PermissionAction")
            .Include("PermissionGroup.GroupActionPermissions.PermissionAction.PermissionController")
            .Include("UserActionPermissions")
            .Include("UserActionPermissions.PermissionAction")
            .Include("UserActionPermissions.PermissionAction.PermissionController")
            .FirstOrDefault();

        // validation..

        return user.ToUserDTO();
    });
}
```

Unfortunelly this is not changing anything. `user.PermissionGroup` is not accessable. What should I do?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499211/entity-framework-detach-an-entity-and-the-related-entities-gone

Comment: How `User` class looks like?